# Soma e média usando jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Gostaria de saber se este código possui algum erro ou não

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calcular a soma ou média de dois valores</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calcular a soma ou média de dois valores</h1>
    <%
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            double valor1 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valor1"));
            double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valor2"));
            String operacao = request.getParameter("operacao");
            double resultado = 0;

            if (operacao.equals("soma")) {
                resultado = valor1 + valor2;
            } else if (operacao.equals("media")) {
                resultado = (valor1 + valor2) / 2;
            }
    %>
    <h2>Resultado</h2>
    <p>O resultado da operação selecionada é: <%= resultado %></p>
    <%
        } else {
    %>
    <form method="post" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/index.jsp">
        <label for="valor1">Valor 1:</label>
        <input type="number" name="valor1" id="valor1">
        <br>
        <label for="valor2">Valor 2:</label>
        <input type="number" name="valor2" id="valor2">
        <br>
        <label>Operação:</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="soma" checked>
            Soma
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="media">
            Média
        </label>
        <br>
            <button type="submit">Calcular</button>
    </form>
    <%
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ao acessar esta JSP vc recebeu algum erro? Se sim, qual? Eu testei aqui e tanto a operação de soma quanto a de média funcionaram normalmente. A única coisa ruim que notei foram uns caracteres estranhos que estava aparecendo no lugar das letras com acento. Para resolver isso, adicione isto ao topo do seu arquivo: `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`. Também é boa prática adicionar isto ao início do seu `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` (é importante que esta metatag seja o primeiro filho do seu `<head>`).

Answer (score -3):

Não é possível determinar se o código tem algum erro sem mais contexto sobre o sistema em que ele está sendo executado e suas dependências. No entanto, o código parece ser um JSP (JavaServer Pages) que realiza uma operação matemática simples com base em valores fornecidos pelo usuário através de um formulário HTML e exibe o resultado na página. A operação pode ser uma soma ou uma média, dependendo da seleção do usuário. Certifique-se de que as dependências do sistema estejam instaladas corretamente e que o código esteja sendo executado no ambiente adequado antes de avaliar se há erros.